# How can I return a physical file from the server on page load using ASP.NET Core / Razor?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to download a file automatically on page load if a certain server-side variable is not empty.

Here is my code in Index.cshtml:

```
<script>
function downloadZip() {
    @if (Model.zipPath != "")
    {
        Model.ReturnZipFile();
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is my code in Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult ReturnZipFile()
    {
        return PhysicalFile(zipPath, "application/zip", "testFileName.zip");
    }
```

Everything runs with no exceptions but no file download prompt appears. I'm assuming the way I'm doing this is fundamentally wrong for some reason, but I'm not sure why.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's fundamentally incorrect and it wouldn't work. You need JavaScript code to call the endpoint and download the file. You can @ ping me if you want me to expand with an answer

Comment: As @CamiloTerevinto said code in the post makes no sense and as result does not explain what you want to achieve. I believe that you want to "return file or HTML based on condition" - so I picked duplicate that shows how to do that. If you are looking for something else please [edit] the question to clarify that (and explain why my suggestion  did not work) so question can be possibly reopened (or better duplicate suggested).